# Lots of classed are getting loaded by default

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I am just running a Test java class and using JProfiler to see what all classes has been loaded in memory during the run and its showing me lots of classes as shown in the image below, I am curious from where all of these classes are coming, does bootstrap loader load all rt.jar classes when JVM starts by default as I am not using all of these classes in my program

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int i =0;
        Thread.sleep(100000000);
    }
}
```

Please have a look at this:
[JProfile data image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7sOU.png)

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVHdq.png)

Comment: At least all classes that yours depend on (recursively), and all necessary classes at runtime are loaded. Yes, a lot of them are necessary... Nothing surprising in your screenshot... Very basic ones.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès 
  I have added one more image and I can see classes under java.util.concurrent , java.nio, java.util.stream and lots of other classed have been loaded, why are they necessary?

Comment: The additional classes in the second image are the result of JProfiler’s presence. As a side note, you should use the function to export this table as text (there surely is one) and include this textual form in your question, instead of using screenshots.

Comment: Thanks Jean and Holger , so boot strap loader does not load anything in advance unless its needed at run time?
@Holgeris there any way to exclude these jprofiler classes and only see the rest.

Comment: @vaibhav You can use `jdeps` tool to analyse (at class level) the dependencies of your code.

Comment: @vaibhav You may also read [class loading mechanism by Oracle](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/how-the-jvm-locates-loads-and-runs-libraries)

Comment: You may run your test program like `java -verbose:class Test` from command line, without any additional tools. Then, you see all classes always loaded during a normal startup.